# Deep Learning UNet convergence

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am writting a deep learning UNet Model for image segmentation of **RGB 256 * 256p images** -> **grayscale images** 
Inspiration comes from
https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet,
so my Neural Net has the following structure:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 256, 256, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 256, 256, 16) 448         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 256, 256, 16) 64          conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 256, 256, 16) 2320        batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 256, 256, 16) 64          conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 128, 128, 16) 0           batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 128, 32) 4640        max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, 128, 128, 32) 128         conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 128, 32) 9248        batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, 128, 128, 32) 128         conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           batch_normalization_4[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 64)   18496       max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, 64, 64, 64)   256         conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 64)   36928       batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, 64, 64, 64)   256         conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 32, 32, 64)   0           batch_normalization_6[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 32, 128)  73856       max_pooling2d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (BatchNor (None, 32, 32, 128)  512         conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 32, 32, 128)  147584      batch_normalization_7[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (BatchNor (None, 32, 32, 128)  512         conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 32, 32, 128)  0           batch_normalization_8[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 16, 16, 128)  0           dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 16, 16, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_4[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (BatchNor (None, 16, 16, 256)  1024        conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 16, 16, 256)  590080      batch_normalization_9[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (BatchNo (None, 16, 16, 256)  1024        conv2d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 16, 16, 256)  0           batch_normalization_10[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 32, 32, 256)  0           dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 128)  131200      up_sampling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 32, 32, 256)  0           dropout_1[0][0]                  
                                                                 conv2d_11[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 128)  295040      concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (BatchNo (None, 32, 32, 128)  512         conv2d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 128)  147584      batch_normalization_11[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (BatchNo (None, 32, 32, 128)  512         conv2d_13[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           batch_normalization_12[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 64)   32832       up_sampling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           conv2d_6[0][0]                   
                                                                 conv2d_14[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 64)   73792       concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_13 (BatchNo (None, 64, 64, 64)   256         conv2d_15[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 64)   36928       batch_normalization_13[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_14 (BatchNo (None, 64, 64, 64)   256         conv2d_16[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 128, 128, 64) 0           batch_normalization_14[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 32) 8224        up_sampling2d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 128, 128, 64) 0           conv2d_4[0][0]                   
                                                                 conv2d_17[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 32) 18464       concatenate_3[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (BatchNo (None, 128, 128, 32) 128         conv2d_18[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_19 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 32) 9248        batch_normalization_15[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_16 (BatchNo (None, 128, 128, 32) 128         conv2d_19[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_4 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 256, 256, 32) 0           batch_normalization_16[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_20 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 16) 2064        up_sampling2d_4[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_4 (Concatenate)     (None, 256, 256, 32) 0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
                                                                 conv2d_20[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_21 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 16) 4624        concatenate_4[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_17 (BatchNo (None, 256, 256, 16) 64          conv2d_21[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_22 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 16) 2320        batch_normalization_17[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_18 (BatchNo (None, 256, 256, 16) 64          conv2d_22[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_23 (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 2)  290         batch_normalization_18[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_19 (BatchNo (None, 256, 256, 2)  8           conv2d_23[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 256, 256, 2)  0           batch_normalization_19[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
MLP_layer (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 1)  3           dropout_3[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
```

*However, convergence is very hard*, it works only with very restricted set of parameters:
 - **learning rate** not greater than 1e-3, in some article then use 1e-2 with a Decay
 - **First Convolution filter number** just works with 16 (32 next layer, etc...)
 - **batch size** 8 or 16 while 32 and 64 are not working
 - **batch_normalization** is necessary, instead it's not in the example base model. This is supposed to help the network to learn with less restricted parameters as mentionned in ... https://towardsdatascience.com/batch-normalization-theory-and-how-to-use-it-with-tensorflow-1892ca0173ad? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf

*Another details:*
 - I checked that my inputs are `np.float32` ranging from 0 to 1
 - I am trying to learn satellite image cadasters

So my question is:

*Why my network is not working with the same parameters that are used in the reference article?*

-> I had to put "slow" parameters to make it works (lower learning rate, lower batch size, less convolution layers ...). Else it outputs a grey image with a single pixel value,

Code used:

```
SHAPE=256
DIM=3
INITIALIZER='glorot_uniform'
BASE_SIZE=16
LR=0.001


def get_model(pretrained_model: str = None, input_size: tuple_int = (SHAPE, SHAPE, DIM)) -> Sequential:
"""
Machine learning model for image learning, here the purpose is segmentation,
thus there should be upsampling !!

Parameters
----------
pretrained_model: str
    name of .hdf5 file containing pretrained weights, syntax: 'dir:weight.hfd5'
input_size: tuple_int

Returns
-------
Sequential
"""
if pretrained_model:
    return read_model(pretrained_model)
else:
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(inputs)
    batch_norm1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(batch_norm1)
    batch_norm2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(batch_norm2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 2, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(pool1)
    batch_norm3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 2, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(batch_norm3)
    batch_norm4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(batch_norm4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 4, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(pool2)
    batch_norm5 = BatchNormalization()(conv5)

    conv6 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 4, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(batch_norm5)
    batch_norm6 = BatchNormalization()(conv6)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(batch_norm6)

    conv7 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(pool3)
    batch_norm7 = BatchNormalization()(conv7)

    conv8 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(batch_norm7)
    batch_norm8 = BatchNormalization()(conv8)

    drop4 = Dropout(0.2)(batch_norm8)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv9 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 16, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(pool4)
    batch_norm9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 16, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(
        batch_norm9)
    batch_norm10 = BatchNormalization()(conv10)

    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(batch_norm10)

    up6 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 8, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(
        UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(drop5))
    merge6 = concatenate([drop4, up6], axis=3)

    conv11 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(merge6)
    batch_norm11 = BatchNormalization()(conv11)

    conv12 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 8, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(
        batch_norm11)
    batch_norm12 = BatchNormalization()(conv12)

    up7 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 4, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(
        UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(batch_norm12))
    merge7 = concatenate([conv6, up7], axis=3)
    conv13 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 4, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(merge7)
    batch_norm13 = BatchNormalization()(conv13)

    conv14 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 4, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(
        batch_norm13)
    batch_norm14 = BatchNormalization()(conv14)

    up8 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 2, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(
        UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(batch_norm14))
    merge8 = concatenate([conv4, up8], axis=3)

    conv15 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 2, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(merge8)
    batch_norm15 = BatchNormalization()(conv15)

    conv16 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE * 2, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(
        batch_norm15)
    batch_norm16 = BatchNormalization()(conv16)

    up9 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(
        UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(batch_norm16))
    merge9 = concatenate([conv2, up9], axis=3)

    conv17 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(merge9)
    batch_norm17 = BatchNormalization()(conv17)

    conv18 = Conv2D(BASE_SIZE, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(batch_norm17)
    batch_norm18 = BatchNormalization()(conv18)

    conv19 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer=INITIALIZER)(batch_norm18)
    batch_norm19 = BatchNormalization()(conv19)

    # personall add
    drop4 = Dropout(0.2)(batch_norm19)

    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation='sigmoid', name='MLP_layer')(drop4)

    model = Model(input=inputs, output=conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=LR),
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy', iou_loss])

    return model
```

Thanks

Comment: Faced similar issues working with Unet. `BatchNormalization` is essential, also low `batch_sizes` and learning rates. Would be interested in a proper answer as well.

Comment: what was the goal of your UNet? Image segmentation too? @Anakin

Comment: Yes. On satellite data.

Comment: @Anakin https://project.inria.fr/aerialimagelabeling/ ? This is the "challenge I am trying to solve"

Comment: can you post the code used to create the network? are you definitely using a sigmoid at the last layer?

Comment: Hello, I just added the code, and yes `'sigmoid'` is used on MLP layer

Comment: Learning rate for me is usually about 1e-4, -3 might be OK but -2 may not converge for this kind of network.

Comment: To my knowledge, the dropout is nothing of interest for UNet. BatchNorm is. Dropout can be counter productive.

Comment: About batch size : try evaluating memory usage with different sizes. Are you getting memory warnings from tensorflow?

Comment: @SimonCaby Yes I can get memory Warning, even Errors, for batch size 32 and 64 with tensorflow GPU on NVIDIA Quadro P500  2GB

Comment: I usually work with 12GB for this kind of network. 2GB is small hence small batches.

Comment: 32 and 64 batches have been tested on AWS, no memory issues but the net output a constant grey image, whatever the input is

Answer (score 2):

Binary crossentropy doesn't work well with segmentation problems, especially if you have class imbalance. For example if the masks contain much more black pixels than white pixels on average, then your neural net feels ok to predict everything to be black. Try to use Dice loss or Jaccard loss as your objective function, or you can use a sum of Dice or Jaccard with binary crossentropy, or weighted binary crossentropy. At last, you can take a look at this library https://segmentation-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html which contains some segmentation models, including Unet with different pretrained encoders and the most common metrics on this topic (such as Dice and Jaccard).